# Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1) when using kmeans

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I m trying to do clustering with kmeans in r, but it gives error

```
Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(x) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
```

This is the code

```
Cluster_df <- kmeans(cluster_data, 2, algorithm = "Forgy")
```

also tried with

```
Cluster_df <- kmeans(cluster_data, 2, algorithm = "Lloyd")
```

here is the dataset

```
> dput(cluster_data)
structure(list(Value = c(1.2, 40.8, 3.7, 39.5, 2.3, 10.8, 1, 
1.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0), Type = c("1 rk", "1 bhk", "1.5 bhk", "2 bhk", 
"2.5 bhk", "3 bhk", "3.5 bhk", "4 bhk", "4.5 bhk", "5 bhk", "5.5 bhk"
)), .Names = c("Value", "Type"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -11L), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(
    Value = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"
    )), Type = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("Value", "Type")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

And this is the version of `R` I am using

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.0                         
year           2017                        
month          04                          
day            21                          
svn rev        72570                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
nickname       You Stupid Darkness
```

Comment: What package are you using to create your object `cluster_data`? And where does function `do_one` come from? Whenever you use an external package you should start the script with a call to `library(pkgname)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas `clusterd_data` is the data imported from csv file whose content has been posted as well

Comment: @RuiBarradas I haven't imported any new package while writing the code, I just imported data from csv into object `clusterd_data` and used the function of `kmeans()`

Comment: OK, got it. The problem is that `kmeans` wants a numeric matrix as its first argument and your data has a column, the second, that is not numeric.

Answer (score 0):

K-means *can* only handle continuous variables.

Otherwise, it cannot compute the *mean*.

Answer (score 0):

While uploading the data, use "row.names = 1".
For example,
UBS <- read.csv("UBS.csv", row.names = 1)

see if that helps, works for me.